# Access query to Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, ms-access

In an Access database I have a query table that is linked to a form when the form is opened and edited.

How can I link this query table to Excel so the when I click a button on the form in Access the spreadsheet in Excel is opened showing all items in the Access query table, the user can then edit the spreadsheet if required.

All in Access/Excel 2003

Answer (score 1):

FollowHyperlink can be a useful way to open a document of any type with its registered application:

```
FollowHyperlink "C:\SomeDir\BookX.xls"  ''Excel
FollowHyperlink "C:\SomeDir\"  ''Explorer
FollowHyperlink "mailto:example@example.com" ''Default email
```

More: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa204494%28office.10%29.aspx

If you wish to manipulate the Excel file after you have opened it, it may be best to use Automation:

```
   Dim strFileName As String
   Dim objXL Object
   Dim wkb As Object

   ''New instance, GetObject for existing instance
   Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  
   objXL.Visible = True

   strFileName = "C:\Docs\LTD.xls"
   Set wkb = objXL.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)

   ''Do stuff

   ''Give control to user
   objXLS.UserControl = True
```

Comment: Uh, this looks like a snippet of late binding code incompletely rewritten to use early binding. With the reference, you don't need the CreateObject statement -- you would instead use the New keyword (either in your variable declaration or in the Set statement). For late binding (i.e., requiring no reference) you could keep the CreateObject and replace "As Excel.Application" and "As Excel.Workbook" with "As Object".

Answer (score 0):

(I'm using 2007, but same applies)
In the button's click event (use code builder, not macro), the code

`Shell "excel.exe " & Chr(34) & "C:\FullPathToYourFile\file.xls" & Chr(34), vbMaximizedFocus`

will do it, although inelegantly. Missing out the `chr(34)` breaks with paths or filenames with spaces in them, and although wrapping the path with `'` should work in it's place, it isn't on my 2007 version.

I am not familiar with how to do it in macros, or if it's possible.